# Editing a list in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, indexing

Here's the code I've written:

```
lines = ['add something to this line',
         'add nothing to this one',
         'emphasize this line',
         'emphasize nothing, instead remove a "count" number of characters from the end']

count = 0
new_lines = []
for n,line in enumerate(lines):
    if n > 0:
        if lines[n-1][:4] == line[:4]:
            new_lines.pop(-1)
            new_lines.append(lines[n-1] + '!!!')
            count += 3
    elif n == len(lines)-1:
        line = line[:-count]
    new_lines.append(line)
```

The `new_lines` is fine but for the final line. Shouldn't it be truncated?

```
['add something to this line!!!',
 'add nothing to this one',
 'emphasize this line!!!',
 'emphasize nothing, instead remove a "count" number of characters from the end']
```

EDIT: I meant to write `len(lines)`, not `len(new_lines)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your logic:

```
if n > 0:
    ...
elif n == len(new_lines)-1:
    line = line[:-count]
```

First of all, this could work only on the *first* line of the list: after that, `n` is positive, so you don't get to this `else` part.  For the line you expect to change, `n` is 3, so you're stuck in the `if/True` clause.

Next, `n` is always equal to len(new_lines at this point).  Your `elif` condition is algebraically False.

If you want to alter the last line, try

```
if n == len(lines)-1:
```

Output:

```
add something to this line!!!
add nothing to this one
emphasize this line!!!
emphasize nothing, instead remove a "count" number of characters from t
```

Answer (score 1):

No, because `elif n == len(new_lines)-1:` will never be `True`. Here are the actual values:

```
n, len(new_lines)-1
0, -1
1, 0
2, 1
3, 2
```

After the first iteration, `if n > 0:` will always be `True` so you will never enter this block: `elif n == len(lines)-1:`. Change the `elif` to `if` and you get the behavior you want.

Comment: I think I meant to say len(lines), sorry. It outputs the same kind of list too.